# Using Cascade Delete

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use `On Cascade Delete.` When I delete records from the parent table `Delete from customers where customer_Id=3`, the child record is still there and I cant figure out what i am missing. How should my code look for this to work?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers /* Parent table */
( 
customer_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstName VARCHAR(30),
lastName VARCHAR(30),
userName VARCHAR(30),
password VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(customer_Id),
UNIQUE KEY(userName)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders /* Child table */
(
item_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_cost DOUBLE,
item_name VARCHAR(30),
customer_Id INT NOT NULL,
userName VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(item_Id),

CONSTRAINT First_Foreign_Key1 
FOREIGN KEY fk_customer_id(customer_Id)
REFERENCES customers(customer_Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
on DELETE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT Second_Foreign_Key2 
FOREIGN KEY fk_userName(userName)
REFERENCES customers(userName)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set foreign_key_checks=0. The foreign keys were disabled. It needs to be set to 1, then it works.